# Googleplayservices v2 revision 12 is giving nullpointerexception

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I have recently updated my Google play services in eclipse up to revision 12, 
i have re-imported the lib in my eclipse but after that I'm having null-pointer exception at

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

but i have already initialized map as

this happens with all the older projects wherever i have used Google play services as a lib and I'm showing Google map,and I'm checking in a emulator

EDIT: after some refreshing and couple of more times re-importing the lib now I'm having this error

```
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:284)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at com.example.googlemapscreenshot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-26 03:35:44.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1537):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can that be the emulator problem?

EDIT as per GrlsHu:

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/snap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Snap Shot" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
Button snap;
double latti, longi;
ImageView imgv;
ArrayList<String> strlist;
String mPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    snap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.snap);
    imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


    strlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    latti = 17.4721005;
    longi = 78.3443972;

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latti, longi)).title("Office").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))).showInfoWindow();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latti,longi), 15.0f));

    snap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                Bitmap bitmap;

                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                    bitmap = snapshot;
                    try {
                        mPath = "/mnt/sdcard/"+ "MyMapScreen";
                        File imageFile = new File(mPath);
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

                        // above "/mnt ..... png" => is a storage path (where image will be stored) + name of image you can customize as per your Requirement

                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            map.snapshot(callback);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));
            imgv.setImageURI(uri);
    }
    });
}
}
```

EDIT: Ok my problem is solved, i might had some problem with my system,after i restarted my system its working properly, but now i have a different prblem

you can see my above code, whenever im hitting the button, it should take one snapshot and save it into my sdcard, but its giving no class def found as

```
                SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
```

does anyone know about the snapshotreadycallback function and why i might get this error?

Comment: Where is your logcat ?

Comment: What is in this line `com.example.googlemapscreenshot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)` ?

Comment: @GrlsHu it points to this line      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    inside oncreate

Comment: Can you post your whole layout file code? also some more code of your MainActivity's onCreate() method?

Comment: i am trying to get snapshot of the maps so i have done this, please check the code

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully below code willl be helpfull

instead of directly initializing `map`, do the following to initialize the `map`

```
if (map == null) {
// Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

Inside this `if condition`, write your required code .

Comment: I"m initializing map at on create so obviously it will be null after declaration

Comment: you are right but you first said your app was crashing with nullPointerException so i suggested this, i also initially faced the same problem but doing this solved mine

Comment: @Ari use latest api Image that is Android 4.3 API Emulator as of now.